# How to convert Range to List or Array in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to convert a range of Int into a a List or an Array.
I have this code working in Scala 2.8:

```
var years: List[Int] = List()
val firstYear = 1990
val lastYear = 2011

firstYear.until(lastYear).foreach(
  e => years = years.:+(e)
)
```

I would like to know if there is another syntax possible, to avoid using foreach, I would like to have no loop in this part of code.

Thanks a lot!

Loic

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `toList` method:

```
scala> 1990 until 2011 toList
res2: List[Int] = List(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010)
```

`toArray` method converts `Range` to array.

Comment: Thanks! This works for `Iterator`s too, which I was looking for

Answer (score 19):

And there's also this, in addition to the other answers:

```
List.range(firstYear, lastYear)
```

Answer (score 12):

`Range` has a `toList` and a `toArray` method:

```
firstYear.until(lastYear).toList

firstYear.until(lastYear).toArray
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply:

```
(1990 until 2011).toList
```

but don't forget that `until` does *not* include the last number (stops at 2010). If you want 2011, use `to`:

```
(1990 to 2011).toList
```